# Specifying action filter at the controller level Versus at the action method level, which will run first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

When I create an asp.net MVC 5 web project, I check the Account controller and I find the following code:-

```
 [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }
        // GET: /Account/Login
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

where they specify [Authorize] at the controller level, and [AllowAnonymous] at the action method level. I thought that asp.net mvc will check first all the action filters at the controller level and if they successed it will processed with the action method call. But seems that this is not the situation, because anonymous users can call the login action method, although  [Authorize] is specified at the controller level ? so what is the scenario here?

Thanks

Comment: Answer is the `[AllowAnonymous]` in your method will override the `[Authorize]` in the controller. But trust me it will be much easier to simply create a new mvc project and try that out since anyways you have to write the code :)

Comment: but is this specific to [AllowAnonymous] ,or always action method's action filter will override the controller's action filters ?

Comment: That is very depending. The "override" is just a result of action filter's [running order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). It is basically First -> Global -> Controller -> Action -> Last order, and in this specific case, the action level `[AllowAnonymous]` runs later and override the effect of controller level `[Authorize]` (**but both action filter runs**). You may have to either study into detail mechanism of each filter, or as I said, simply test them out when you need to use 2 conflicting filter.

Comment: but of both action filters runs, then the anonymous user will be redirected to the login page, before [allowanonymous ] is reached ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by having a look at the Authorize attribute source code to understand how it works:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs

Have a closer look at the OnAuthorization method: you will see it looks for an AllowAnonymous Attribute on the action or the controller and skip the authorization if it find any.

```
bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true)
                                 || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), inherit: true);

if (skipAuthorization)
{
     return;
}
```